# Using shell commands with boot2docker

Tags: linux, bash, shell, boot2docker

I have created a boot2docker VirtualBox instance, I can SSH into it OK but then when I try and run any commands such as `bash` I get

```
-sh: bash: not found
```

Pretty sure I'm missing something really simple but can't see what.

Looking in /bin it doesn't look to contain bash

I'm pretty new to the *nix world so be gentle

Comment: You'll need to install `bash` if you want to use it. BTW your post as framed is not in the context of programing, which is the main focus of this site, and is probably better asked elsewhere, Super User maybe.  That said, Boot2Docker is based on Tiny Core Linux so you'd have to install `bash` using the Tiny Core Extension installer however this will not be retained if booting from the `boot2docker.iso` unless you build a custom boot2docker ISO Image.  You can find how to install `bash` on Boot2Docker, or customize the ISO Image, on the Internet using Google just like I did.

Comment: Thanks. I did have a good look on Google before posting here but didn't have any luck. Guillermo was really helpful below and was able to answer my question luckily :)

Comment: Instead of posting a comment, having given you relevant searchable information, I could have instead posted as an answer providing the exact command line including relevant URL(s) however when a question asked shows no effort to have helped oneself resolve the issue first then I'm just not going to!  Before your post I had never heard of Boot2Docker however in 5 minutes I downloaded the boot2docker.iso, had it running in a VM, installed bash and all from a couple of Google searches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to run command "tce"  then you can search for "bash" and it will give option to install.  More info at: http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:install_apps